# Rendering database objects in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

This is a basic question but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

I'm trying to render a detail view in my django site, but my calls to get the object are just failing or else not rendering.

Here is what I have:
views.py

```
from django.template import loader
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import user_profile

def detail(request, content_id):
   template = loader.get_template('profiles/detail.html')

   profile = user_profile.objects.get(pk=content_id)
   context = {'profile': profile}

   return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Within the template, I have simply been testing the calls using:

```
<h1>{{ profile }}</h1>
<h1>{{ profile.name }}</h1>
```

This is my first time rendering this from scratch, I know I'm missing something dumb I just can't sort it. Thank you!

**edit** This current setup receives a 500 error. Without the get(pk) statement it loads, but doesn't show the variables, just the rest of my HTML.

upon request, here is the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns=[
   path('<int:content_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
   ]
```

**edit: solution** Solved! Ends up there was an issue with the model where a migration was not properly performed and a column was read as missing.

Comment: show your urls.py

Comment: please set your `settings.DEBUG`  to `True` and add the error traceback into your question (there's a some button to display copypaste-friendly traceback on the error page)

Comment: if the profile does not exist with your "content_id", an error may occur

Comment: Due to security protocols, debug is set to true but further logging is prevented unfortunately... and I've confirmed that the content_id exists by viewing the postgres database directly...

Answer (score 0):

Model was contained a column that was missing in the database. Even though it was not being called, it still resulted in an error when the model was referenced.